# Google Sheets API, Read Values by Filter

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am trying to use Google Sheets API with PHP for reading and writing values to google spreadsheet. At the moment I can write values inside the sheet using [append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method.

The problem is I am trying to read only the rows that match some condition like 'date beetween' or 'user name'. For the purpose I think I have to use this method [batchGetByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGetByDataFilter), but I am not sure exactly how to implement it in my php script.

This is part of my code:

```
    $client = GoogleSheets::getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    $spreadsheetId = '1nZ0ybxUucbeNPVE_opKLdSFJVHmWIo1hVcvuQA4H-aY';
    $range = 'Sheet1!A2:J';

    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGetByDataFilter($spreadsheetId);
    echo "Return Values From Spreadsheet: \n";
    var_dump($response);exit;
    
    return $response->getValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter) only filters by [developer metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter#developermetadatalookup) and by [ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) but not by values.

To achieve this, you will have to get a specific range of values and loop through them, returning only the matched values. You can copy the code from the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) which returns values from a Sheet. Change the Sheet Id and the Range to fit your needs. Also, once it finds data, you should use an [if condition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

```
...

if (empty($values)) {
    print "No data found.\n";
} else {
    print "Data found.\n";
    foreach ($values as $row) {

        // Print column A if there is a match
        if ($row[0] == "some username"){
            printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I made it like that, after I was searching for some info or examples. :)

Comment: That's sad google hasn't provided filter options for getting data. If the spreadsheet is large and we don't really know where data (withing rows or columns is storred) is we need to get all values and iterate through them, which is ridiculous regarding time and performance.

Comment: There's a feature request in Google's Bug Tracker to [retrieve only the hidden/ not-hidden values](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128600464). It's stalling since 2019 though.