# How to get value of filtered spreadsheets using google sheets api?

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api

i need to showing data from sheet based on user keyword.
i try using setBasicFilter to filter data.

Here example requestbody.

```
$query = [
        'requests' => [
            [
                'setBasicFilter' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        'range' => [
                            'sheetId' => 0,
                            'startColumnIndex' => 0,
                            'endColumnIndex' => 14,
                            'startRowIndex' => 0
                        ],
                        'sortSpecs' => [
                            [
                                'dimensionIndex' => 0,
                                'sortOrder' => 'DESCENDING'
                            ],
                            [
                                'dimensionIndex' => 2,
                                'sortOrder' => 'ASCENDING'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'filterSpecs' => [
                            [
                                'columnIndex' => 2,
                                'filterCriteria' => [
                                    'condition' => [
                                        'type' => 'TEXT_CONTAINS',
                                        'values' => [
                                            [
                                                'userEnteredValue' => 'input'
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

but, its only change view data on the spreadsheets, and response only return empty.

Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution after seeing this issue [Google Sheets API, Read Values by Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789700/google-sheets-api-read-values-by-filter/62793462#62793462)

you can use foreach() than use if() to get data that you need to filter.

example :

```
foreach ($data['values'] as $key => $value) {
    
    if($value[2] === 'input') {

        // $key . $value
    }
}
```